# how do i call azure service bus from windows universal app

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, win-universal-app

I am developing a windows universal app and I would like to make calls to the Azure Service Bus.  I can find packages for a few Azure services (such as storage) but can't find anything for communication with the Service Bus.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Good news!

While we wait for a proper Microsoft-developed package to arrive, you can use this:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureSBLite/

AzureSBLite is basically code-compatible with all the ServiceBus Libraries, so the syntax remains identical, and it allows you to use it in UWP apps